# Suspicious folders in .well-known/acme-challenge after hacking incident

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress website of mine was hacked and I'm deleting everything except the public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge folder. When I opened it, I found other folders inside that were last modified yesterday, February 27, 2024.

I'm not sure if it's normal for these folders to exist on the server or if I should delete them too.

The .well-known/acme-challenge folder is used for Let's Encrypt SSL certificate validation, but I'm concerned these additional folders may be malicious since my site was recently hacked.

Can someone advise if these additional folders within .well-known/acme-challenge are expected or if I should remove them as part of the clean up after the hacking incident? Any guidance is appreciated.

On another site where I also have the .well-known folder, I don't have any other folders inside, which confuses me. I'm not knowledgeable about this topic.
[image]